# GIT - Use the latest version of the file from all branches

Tags: git, version, branch, git-checkout

Do you know how to use **the latest** version of the file from **all branches**? The problem is that to use the latest version, I have to checkout the branch, but I do not know which branch is the latest version.

So I may use a file that is obsolete from another branch, but I do not know that another branch has the last version.

*Partial Solution: Create a new branch where the last version of the file will be.*

**Can it be solved otherwise? Thanks**

Comment: You should check branches with history and you will find the latest changes and commits with time that will help you to fine latest branches of all. If you are not familiar with command line, you can also use GUI tools like https://tortoisegit.org/ for windows, https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ for Mac.

Comment: @HoumerX: in your repository, what indicates the **latest** version ?

Comment: @LeGEC: The last version I think is the last modified file.

Comment: @NikhilParmar: I'm looking for some other option so I do not have to switch to all branches. I'm using Git Extensions.

Comment: @HoumerX View Commit Log is not helpful to you? The latest file will be based on latest author date. Will this help?

Comment: @HoumerX: Could you please explain how you use branches ?

Comment: Well, I've solved it this way:gitk --all -- \repository\file. Shows the log from all branches of the file.

Comment: `git log --all path/to/file` did the trick for me. The point was that I had been working on translating a string table file using different versions of a tool that was in development, and once the tool was finished I also wanted to contribute the actual translation work already done but had lost track of what test branches had the latest versions of the translated file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would guess that you using git the wrong way if you're asking this kind of question.
The notion of "latest version" of a file has no real sense in git.
The notion of "next version to be released" of a file depends on your branch and release workflow, but should be deterministic.

Maybe you should explain your root need for better understanding of want you're trying to achieve.

---

But, to strictly answer your question:

To find the latest commit that modified a file:

```
git log -1 --date-order --all --format=format:%H -- path/to/file/in/repository
```

This will give you the commit hash.

If you want to retrieve the content of the file in this commit:

```
git show ${COMMIT_HASH}:path/to/file/in/repository
```

If you want to find the branches containing this commit:

```
git branch --contains ${COMMIT_HASH}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a single development environment without containers. So if I need to deploy a file, I have to find the most up-to-date file from all branches.

Comment: I don't see the correlation between not using containers and the need to fin the most up-to-date file version.

Comment: I had the same question. My use case is that on my feature branch, there is a problem in one Makefile (unrelated to the feature) that is likely common to all branches. I'd like to know whether that has been fixed somewhere else. (Perhaps I mean something else than the OP though: What's the current version of the file on each branch, and what are the differences to mine.